# Task list view by current user

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, tasklist

I have a task list. I want to hide tasks from current user if the task is not assigned to him/her or task is not assigned to his/her department.
There must be 3 levels: Boss, Manager, and user.
Boss can see every task.
Manager can see all tasks of his department. Also, he/she can be Manager to more than one department.
User can see all tasks of his department.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions that needs answering before one could give an definitive answer since the question asked includes some ambiguity. So in this answer I will this purpose also give a general description of some of the challenges.

**Hidden or no permission**

If a user don't have permission to view a task list item it is therefor also "hidden". But there is also the possibility to hide a list item (for instance with a view in its simplest form). In the latter case it is still possible to retrieve the information of the task list item by appropriate navigation to the task list item. In some cases this is a perfectly fine solution, in others it is not. The solution must then include setting the correct *permission* on the site collection, web, task list(s) or specific items in a task list (or maybe all created task lists?). Depending on the requirements this may take different forms. In its simplest form you only have one task list.

**Audiences**

If the number of departments are few then the same audiences could be configured in Sharepoint and once audiences is enabled on the task list an appropriate content query web part could be added to a page. This would take care of the problem of only displaying task list items belonging to the users department. Adding a simple filter on the content query web part would take care of not displaying task list items assigned to different users than the current logged in user.

Any user that is part of many AD-groups should, if the audiences is set up correctly, also benefit of this solution.

However:

- audiences add complexity since you have to create and configure them
  and also set the correct audience on task list items.
- a content query web part is,well, it's a wave of the past.
- Audiences don't work for the list view web parts.

So, in most cases audiences falls quite short of meeting the requirements.

**Manually adding more column data (not good)**

There is of course the solution of adding more columns to the task list and requiring that all or some of these columns must be set to correspond to different managers up the chain and also department(s). These columns could then be used in the filter view to display only the relevant items. But these solutions often end up with user complaining that it is too difficult to feed data into Sharepoint and therefor not using it. They will solve their problem by some other means (Outlook, I am looking at you!)

**My site**

If my site is configured then the work management api is in play and a user should have all their assigned task list items on display there. Managers on the other hand will not be able to automatically see all the tasks for the departments that the manager is manager of. The content rollup for all these tasks could be accomplished by adding a search web part that retrieves all the tasks that the manager have view (or more) permissions to. This will effectively display all tasks for the manager (assigned to the manager user) and also all other tasks for the departments that the manager is manager of. (At least if the permissions on the site, web, task lists are properly set up! If the permissions in Sharepoint are not set up properly (like if all users including manager all are members of all sites) maybe it would be a good idea to add a lookup list column on the task list where the user can add the responsible department (however, it has not escaped my attention that that kind of solution is not an optimal one.)).

With this solution you would come quite a long way. The downside is that the user would have to navigate to the my site web.

**Search**

Assuming that the permissions are set up properly (and the search service application for that matter!) the way I solve it would be by using search. It would be fully possible to retrieve all tasks by using the search REST api endpoint and basically only using the ones where assigned is equal to that of the logged in user. For all managers it would be equally easy since all returned task list items would be all the items that the manager user has permissions to. (Again, if the permissions are not set up properly in Sharepoint you are in some trouble and the logic responsible for filtering the task list items out will be more complex and perhaps impossible to actually doing practically.) Adding a code web part to a page is not I would say trivial but having an array of task list items in json format and adding these would take a seasoned developer not a day to complete. I have experience of using knockout for easily creating this table. There should be ample examples of this on the "internet" :-/. Styling of the table can take a long time but is something than can evolve over time. Clicking on a task list item could just navigate the user to the edit page of the clicked task list item.

Saving the web part to the gallery will make it available to other sites as well.